# Magento 2 Enterprise db split

Tags: magento2, database, magento-enterprise-2

I have one custom module. I want when we split the database then tables related to the specific custom module should go to the sales DB(segregation). Can you please help me how can I do it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You need to configure the secondary DB and check the configurations to then run this command below using your parameters, you can check the step-by-step on **[Magento DevDocs Multidatabases](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/config-guide/multi-master/multi-master_masterdb.html)**.

```
bin/magento setup:db-schema:split-sales --host="localhost" --dbname="magento_sales" --username="magento_sales" --password="magento_sales"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating your own tables via an Install or Update script, you can add a parameter to the getConnection and getTable functions to make sure they are created in the right connection.

A clear example is Magento's quote module which has two functions that connect to the database connectionName 'checkout'.

See:

\Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup::getConnection
\Magento\Quote\Setup\QuoteSetup::getTable

```
$this->getSetup()->getConnection(self::$connectionName);
```

Where $connectionName = "checkout".

If there is no split database setup, the tables will be created in the main database.